# Why does IntelliJ show error for my JavaScript scratch file?

Tags: intellij-idea

I use scratch files extensively but suddenly today I'm seeing an error. This is making formatting/linting not work or be effective, but the code executes just fine if I run the scratch file.

It does not matter which JavaScript language version I select when creating the file.

Version: IntelliJ Ultimate 2017.1.4

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Known issue, please follow [WEB-24263](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24263) for updates.
For now, I'd suggest choosing 'ECMAScript 6' language when creating new scratch file

[image]